# Target same-level child of an element

Tags: css, class, html

Is there an easy way to target all 3rd layer elements?

For example, my right column layout is as follows:

```
<div class=right_column>
 <div class=module>
  <div>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class=different_module>
  <div>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How do I target both non-classed `<div>` elements in this instance without specifying each one individually?

Comment: You have a closing `span` tag without an opening one in both divs.

Comment: it was a re-write mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
div > div > div{
    /*  styles here */
}
```

`>` is a child-selector.

Here it says select and use the `div` that is a child of a `div` that is a child of a `div`.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hbXsE/1/

Note: the HTML you provided has a few missing `div` tags and some closing `span` tags.  I redid it for the example.

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `.right_column > div > div`

`>` is the "Child Selector" - check out [this](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) top-notch article on CSS Tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the selector `div.right_column div div` but it will also match divs nested more deeply. To avoid this on most newer browsers, you could use the child selector, like this: `div.right_column > div > div` but it won't work in older versions of IE